# Local Dev Server Not Outputting All Errors

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I'm having some problems with my local dev environment. I'm getting some php warnings on my production server yet I was not seeing any of these errors on my local server. I'd like to be getting these errors on my local server to prevent surprises when I push to a live server. I've tried messing with some of the error reporting settings in my php like confirming I have error_reporting set to E_ALL, I've even set it up to log to a file as well. Anyone know why?

Comment: Have you set `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` ?

Comment: Not In my php files, would there even be a point since I have them set to display in my php.ini file? Most errors do seem to be showing up. The only thing I haven't had shown up was a warning for headers cannot be modified after they've been sent. Wouldn't show up on my local server but on my production server it did.